# Comma separated values with all rows from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, string-aggregation

I have a Services table with three columns.

Service

```
sr_id lang alias
1     EN    A
1     PA    B
1     HI    C
2     EN    D
2     HI    E
```

Now, I want to output with each service id, lang and alias column will be concatenation of alias for a service.

Sample Output -

```
SR_ID   lang   alias
1       EN     A,B,C
1       PA     A,B,C
1       HI     A,B,C
2       EN     D,E
2       HI     D,E
```

How can I do that with PostgreSQL 9.4?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need them sorted, you can use:

```
select sr_id, lang, string_agg(alias, ',') over () as alias
from services
order by sr_id;
```

Otherwise you need:

```
select s.sr_id, s.lang, t.alias
from services s
join (
   select sr_id, string_agg(alias, ',' order by alias) as alias
   from services 
   group by sr_id
) t on t.sr_id = s.sr_id
order by s.sr_id;
```

Comment: You could put in the inner subquery into a CTE for readability/performance, but +1 anyway

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: putting the group by query into a CTE will not have any impact on performance

Answer (score 0):

Tried to create similar condition with same sample data. Please check below query

```
select a.sr_id , a.lang, b.ALIAS from 
SERVICES a  , 
(
select sr_id , string_agg(ALIAS::text,',') ALIAS
from SERVICES
group by sr_id) b
where a.sr_id = b.sr_id;
```

Comment: It would be better to use an explicit JOIN rather than the old-fashion (pre-1992 old-fashioned) implicit join: `…FROM Services A JOIN (SELECT … ) B ON A.Sr_ID = B.Sr_ID…`.

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. Will take care.